# uwp AutoSuggestBox ItemsSource not working

Tags: xaml, uwp, autosuggest

I have created a simple UWP app. All I want is, whenever the user clicks on the AutoSuggestBox, it needs to show all the items in the ItemsSource as suggestions. A combobox is working fine when I set the DisplayMemberPath but the AutoSuggestBox upon clicking doesn't show the ItemsSource as suggestions. Please help. (In this case when I click on the AutoSuggestBox, it needs to display ABC, BCD)

xaml: MainPage.xaml

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
        <ComboBox Width="120"
                  ItemsSource="{Binding TestList,Mode=OneWay}"
                  SelectedIndex="0"
                  DisplayMemberPath="Name"/>

        <AutoSuggestBox Width="200"
                        Margin="0,20,0,0"
                        ItemsSource="{Binding TestList,Mode=OneWay}"
                        DisplayMemberPath="Name"
                        TextMemberPath="Name"
                        PlaceholderText="Search"/>
    </StackPanel>
```

Code Behind: MainPage.xaml.cs

```
public class Test
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int Id { get; set; }
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// An empty page that can be used on its own or navigated to within a Frame.
    /// </summary>
    public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
    {
        private List<Test> _testList;
        public List<Test> TestList
        {
            get
            {
                _testList = new List<Test>();
                _testList.Add(new Test()
                {
                    Name = "ABC",
                    Id = 1,
                });
                _testList.Add(new Test()
                {
                    Name = "BCD",
                    Id = 2,
                });
                return _testList;
            }
        }

        public MainPage()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
            this.DataContext = this;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

> In this case when I click on the AutoSuggestBox, it needs to display ABC, BCD

Please refer [AutoSuggestBox](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.autosuggestbox?view=winrt-22000) document, *Represents a text control that makes suggestions to users as they enter text using a keyboard or pen (using ink and handwriting recognition). it will filter your data based on the input. Then, set the filtered data as the `ItemsSource` of the AutoSuggestBox to update the suggestion list.* So the drop list only rendered when you typing. and it will not display the drop-list when you click the `AutoSuggestBox`.

For this scenario, the best practice is using `ComboBox` to replace.